# How to add dropzone to laravel upload

Tags: laravel, upload, dropzone.js

I have upload function and view.
Someone could tell me how I should edit my function in controller and view to add dropzone.
Here is my controller and view:

Controller:

```
public function getUpload()
{
    return View::make('foto/upload');
}

public function postUpload()
{

   $file = Input::file('image');
   $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
   $path = 'uploads';
   return $file->move($path, $filename);
}
```

View:

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'foto/upload', 'files' => true))}}
{{Form::file('image')}}
{{Form::submit('Upload')}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

my

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://adres/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://adres/assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://adres/assets/css/dropzone.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adres/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adres/assets/js/dropzone.js"></script>
<style>
body { padding-top: 70px; }
</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Laravel specific question.

But this is how you add a class attribute in `Form::open` method.  You just have to add it into the options array.  like so: `{{Form::open(array('url' => 'foto/upload', 'files' => true, 'class' => 'dropzone'))}}`, as long as it's these "reserved" word: ['method', 'url', 'route', 'action', 'files'], Form::open will just throw your options array property=>value pair into the form element.

Comment: I do like this, but when I trying upload img, display "x", but not a message error. How I could display error? [link](http://img.nostatic.pl/img/a_5488ac2758dcc.jpg)